# T_SQL использование переменной

Tags: sql-server, база-данных, sql

У меня есть код, в котором в запросе `SELECT` существуют много длинных `CASE WHEN`,
которые я использую в этом же SELECT, несколько раз при этом создавая новый `CASE WHEN`. А можно ли с помощью переменной? Внести в нее результат `CASE` и ею пользоваться при построении следующих CASE? Но поскольку запрос приносит таблицу из ДБ и `CASE` высчитывает для каждой строки, то и переменная должна быть внутри `SELECT`...
Я пробовала

```
begin 
declare @ddd as varchar(50);
SELECT @ddd=tbl.field1 from tbl;
```

Но программа пишет:

> "A SELECT statement that assigns a
> value to a variable must not be
> combined with data-retrieval
> operations."

Так возможно ли это?

Comment: @elen0, приведите пример

Comment: Переменной можно присвоить значение, только если запрос возвращает одну строку. Да, пример бы не помешал.

Comment: @msi, нет. Если писать что-то вроде `set @i = (select ...)`, тогда да. необходимо, чтобы запрос возвращал не более одной записи. А вот так, например, можно получить сумму столбца val: `select @i += val from table`

Comment: @pegoopik, чудны дела твои, Господи.

Answer (score 1):

> Так возможно ли это?

Нет. Внутри запроса, который выводит строки вы не можете использовать инициализацию переменных.

Таким образом запрос может выполнять одну из двух функций:

1) инициализацию переменных/таблиц

2) возврат строк.

Тем не менее ваша задача выполняется другими способами. Приведу два из них.

1) последовательные предложения CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT case1, case2, case3
FROM Table T
  CROSS APPLY(
    CASE WHEN <Some Condition> THEN <Expression> 
         ELSE <Expression> END case1
  )CA1
  CROSS APPLY(
    CASE WHEN case1=<Exression> THEN <Expression> 
         ELSE <Expression> END case2
  )CA2
  CROSS APPLY(
    CASE WHEN case2=<Exression> THEN <Expression> 
         ELSE <Expression> END case3
  )CA3
```

2) последовательно вложенные запросы:

```
SELECT case1, case2, case3 
FROM(
  SELECT T.*, 
    CASE WHEN case2=<Exression> THEN <Expression> 
         ELSE <Expression> END case3
  FROM(
    SELECT T.*,
      CASE WHEN case1=<Exression> THEN <Expression> 
           ELSE <Expression> END case2
    FROM(
      SELECT T.*,
        CASE WHEN <Some Condition> THEN <Expression> 
             ELSE <Expression> END case1
      FROM Table T
    )T
  )T
)T
```

Только имейте ввиду, что в последнем случае сервер развернёт ваши выражения в одно большое. И вы можете получить ошибку, связанную со слишком длинным выражением на этапе составления плана запроса.